# Can't run tslint-eslint-rules for TSlint in WebStorm 2016

Tags: webstorm, eslint, tslint

I have installed TSLint and it works just fine with WebStorm 2016.

But after this I have tried to install [tslint-eslint-rules](https://github.com/buzinas/tslint-eslint-rules/blob/master/eslint_tslint.json). Followed instructions on github and added `"rulesDirectory": "node_modules/tslint-eslint-rules/dist/rules"` to my custom tslint.config file. But still tslint-eslint-rules seems not to work you get an error in WebStorm

```
(node_modules\tslint\lib\ruleLoader.js:29 throw new Error....)
```

Can somebody confirm that this eslint ported to TypeScript rules actually can't work with standard TSLint or is this some sort of WebStorm 2016 problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me.

[image]

Please make sure that your local tslint package is specified in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Typescript | TSLint`, TSLint package:, and that `path/to/project/node_modules/tslint-eslint-rules/dist/rules` is added to 'Additional rules directory:' there.
Also, try re-opening the project after changing your settings

Comment: Tnx. Yes it works! My mistake was that I was trying to use rules which are not yet implemented and are marked as _TODO_ in github.